# Open standard new record page from lightning flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, aura

I have a flow on new button of an object to collect some user details. Once user details are entered by user, I want to open standard record create page with details from flow prepopulated.
Values should not be prepopulated through URL because of security reasons.

Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using lwc. Invoke a lwc component from flow and from flow use NavigationMixin to open standard record page.

Refer to below link for [navigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation